# Python: Spawn process in the context of a user's desktop session

Tags: python, linux, session, process, desktop

I'm rewriting a previous question for clarity. I have a python process that runs at start up/reboot. Within that process I would like it to wait until a user logs in and then spawn a processes that uses the context of that users active desktop session and and then can use glfw.  This is specifically for Linux. I have seen some stuff involving dbus in order to get a desktop session context but I was wondering if there is a simple way to accomplish what I wish to achieve. The algorithm/psuedo-code is below.

```
import os

#Python script starts and waits for specific user to login to desktop
session = None
while(session == None): 
    #Check for session and attach if found
    sessions = list_sessions()
    for i in sessions:
        if i.username == "username": 
           session = i 
           break 

#Spawn process with correct context
change_context(session)#psuedo function to change the context
os.popen("program") # program that starts using that desktop session
```

Thank you for your help ahead of time. If I haven't been clear please feel free to ask questions or ask for more details.

Comment: you can use the dbus library to interact with the D-Bus session bus